# Passing array through segue in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, segue

I've been struggling for a few days now with passing an array from my `SecondViewController` to my `FirstViewController` using Swift.

From my research I found that `segue` with `prepareForSegue` would be a viable option but I can't seem to figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

My prepareForSegue in SecondViewController looks like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var DVC: FirstViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FirstViewController
        DVC.mySeguedArray = myIncomeArray
}
```

My FirstViewController looks like this:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
var myIncomeArray: [Income] = []
var mySeguedArray: [Income] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myIncomeArray = mySeguedArray
}
```

Also worth mentioning is that I'm sure I'm populating the array in the `SecondViewController` as I'm testing it by printing out the size of the array when adding new `Income` objects to it. But the array in `FirstViewController` just returns `0` when checking it size after `segue`.

Edit: Added picture of storyboard
[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaHZA.png)

Comment: what does initiate the segue back to first vc? and do you have navigation controller in between or is it a show detail segue or something else?

Comment: I tried now to ctrl + drag on the storyboard from the add button on my add button on the SecondViewController to my FirstViewController but it's only letting me push, modal & custom.

Comment: push is fine, but make sure you put the correct segue id in the attribute inspector

Comment: Getting the following error after creating a push between the button and the FirstViewController.

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'passArray'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'`

Comment: embed the first vc in navigation controller

Comment: if you choose to use push, otherwise you can use modal and I'll put an answer on how to do it once you let me know which one you chose

Comment: That is awesome, I finally managed to send an array with 1 object at least instead of 0. But more objects can't be send. It keeps returning .size() on the array keeps returning 1 even though adding more.

Looks like it only segues the array the first time, after it stops.

Comment: That is a very weird problem, If the preparforsegue is being called properly, then it should pass the whole array

Comment: Added picture of my storyboard at the top, incase there is something wrong there.

Comment: can't see it but I gave you answer below that can at least help figure out where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, use the following prepareforsegue as it helps figure out where the problem could be

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueIdInStoryboard" {
        if let DVC = segue.destinationViewController as? FirstViewController{
            DVC.mySeguedArray = myIncomeArray
        } else {
            print("Data NOT Passed! destination vc is not set to firstVC")
        }
    } else { print("Id doesnt match with Storyboard segue Id") }
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController 
{
     @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
     var myIncomeArray: [Income]!
     var mySeguedArray: [Income]!{
         didSet{
             myIncomeArray = mySeguedArray //no need to call viewDidLoad
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Everything with the segue works fine, but it seems like it creates a new empty `myIncomeArray` every time I navigate to the `SecondViewController`with one exception, if I press the `Back` button from the `FirstViewController`. Then it keeps the data.

Comment: Alright, I have managed to solve the problem. I did it by implementing a prepareForSegue in the `FirstViewController`as well. So I always pass around the same array and not initialise a new one. Thank you all for your answers, I've learned a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that array in Swift are value type. So, when you assign array to some other variable or pass it to some method, the value is passed; not the reference to actual object. When you pass your array to second view controller, it copies the content of your original array. You are then adding to this array which do not change the content of original array.

I would suggest you to create some kind of callback or delegate pattern from second view controller to first view controller to inform the changes such that first view controller would also modify the original array content.

Here is a small portion of code that will help you understand this,

```
let originalArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

var newArray = originalArray

newArray.append("d")

print(originalArray) // prints ["a", "b", "c"]
print(newArray) // prints ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: Alright, I will look into that tomorrow. But as long as I can override the array each time I segue, then it won't be an issue since my FirstViewController is only where I want to display them in a textView.

Answer (score 1):

You can use protocol to pass data between view controllers

```
protocol YourFirstViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func onButtonClicked(yourString: [String])
}
```

For passing data from first view controller to second in your Main view Controller when you want to show your first view controller:

1. you should set main view controller to your view controller delegate, `yourFirstViewController.setDlegate(self)`
2. In FirstViewController you should raise an event to main with `onButtonClicked([String])`
3. In onButtonClicked([String]) you can call secondViewController and pass your array with `onSecondViewController([String])`

   ```
   class MainViewController: UIViewController,YourFirstViewControllerDelegate{
   var yourString = [String]()
   weak var vcFirst: FirstViewController?
   weak var vcSecond: SecondViewController?
   func onFirstViewController(){

       if (self.vcFirst == nil){
           self.vcFirst = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as? FirstViewController
           self.vcFirst!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           self.vcFirst?.setDelegate(youeFirstViewControllerDelegate: self)
       }
       self.setActiveController(viewController: self.vcFirst)

   }

   func onSecondViewController(yourString:[String]){
       if (self.Second == nil){
           self.Second = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
           self.vcSecond!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   self.vcSecond.setArray(yourArray: self.yourArray)
       }
       self.setActiveController(viewController: self.vcSecond)

   }

   ....// your view controller method

   func onButtonClicked(yourString: [String]){
   self.yourString = yourString
   onSecondViewController(yourString:self.yourString)
   }
   ```

In your First view controller

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController{
    weak var yourFirstViewControllerDelegate: YourFirstViewControllerDelegate?
    var yourString = ["test1","test2"]
//  all your overide method should be here
    func setDelegate(yourFirstViewControllerDelegate:  YourFirstViewControllerDelegate){ 
    self.yourFirstViewControllerDelegate = yourFirstViewControllerDelegate
  }

func onButtonClicked(){
     self.yourFirstViewControllerDelegate.onButtonClicked(self.yourString)
    }
```

In your second view controller

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController{
var yourString = [String]
//  all your overide method should be here and you can use your [String]
 func setArray(yourString:[String]){
 self.yourString = yourString
 }
}
```

I have not Mac OS to check my code now please just read this code not copy, I'll edit this code tomorrow